# Error Could Not Find or Load Main Class Twitter4j

Tags: javac

So I have a folder. Inside this folder is a jar file(twitter4j-core-4.04.jar) that my java file(Runner.java) imports and uses like so:

```
package twitter4j;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.StatusUpdate;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
```

I have all the right code -- a properly formatted:
    public class Runner

and a proper main function -- 
    public static void main(String[] args)

I compiled Runner.java using the following command and it compiled without error or warning: javac -cp .:twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar Runner.java

Yet, when I go to run the class file it produced(using: java Runner) I get the error listed in the title. This error also occurs if I run the java command with the cp flag(Ive looked everywhere and used every possible classpath to no avail)

how can I fix this?

Comment: What class not find, Runner.class or Twitter4j.class? Runner.java does have a package?

Comment: Runner.class wasnt found

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a runnable .jar file including your code dependencies like twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar and (possibly) others that this depends on. If you are not using Maven, your IDE probably is capable of generating this kind of .jar file for you.

Comment: Then you have to use the jar tool manually to generate it from the .class files, including also other dependencies and a Manifest file telling the jvm what is the executable main method.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the class with its package.

This command must be executed from outside of folder twitter4j:

```
java -cp blabla.jar twitter4j.Runner
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Right Click on class > Run as > Run Configuration
2. remove main class reference
3. Apply > Close
4. Now again right click on class > run as java application.

It worked for me.